# Flutter Data Letter Chancing

Tags: flutter, dart

I get datas from my database. I keep my datas in database like `Ä°vme HÄ±zlandÄ±rma`. But I want to paste my datas to screen like `İvme Hızlandırma`.

I tried to fix this like below. But my did not solve. How can I solve this problem ?

```
var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
responseJson = utf8.decode(responseJson);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been solved with below code.

```
String responseUtf8Decoded = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
var jsonDecoded = json.decode(responseUtf8Decoded);
```